# How to modify the Bootstrap 3 template is an existing Visual Studio 2017 project

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio, ipad

I have an existing Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core 2.0 project using the default Bootstrap 3 CSS. The project runs as expected, but I had a customer with an iPad Mini complain that the left hand menu did not display properly when the iPad was in portrait mode; however, the menu expands properly when in landscape mode.

On all other devices that I have tested, small screens show a hamburger menu for the left navigation and an expanded menu when the screen size width is above 768px.

I think the problem is related to the @media(min-width: 768px) values. When I load the site in a browser there is what appears to be a 1px state where the hamburger menu is not available and the menu is not expanded. This is only true for the left nav menu, and it prevents any user with an iPad Mini from use left menu navigation.

Here is the only @media section in my CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    width: calc(100% + 220px);
}
```

The website is http://www.reasonpress.net

When I make changes to the bootstrap CSS files in the \lib\bootstrap folder, I don't detect a corresponding behavior change on the site. Any thoughts on how to proceed with troubleshooting would be appreciated.